# Javascript function (with ajax) is not working when onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The Onclick button event is not working with the ajax.js function. I can't figure it out what is the problem and the solution to solve the problem.
Below are my code:

> viewAllProduct.php

```
<td><button id ="editItem" class="btn btn-primary" style="height:40px; font-size:16px;" onclick="productEdit('<?=$row['product_id']?>')">Edit</button></td>
```

> ajax.js

```
function productEdit(id){
    $.ajax({
        url:"./adminView/editItemForm.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{record:id},
        success:function(data){
            $('.allContent-section').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Check your console. Is the request being fired?

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons on the page as per the above? If yes that is another problem as `id` attributes must be unique

Comment: The problem is the button is not working when clicked. The console show that Uncaught ReferenceError: productEdit is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple buttons on the page but the others are working well. Only this Edit Button is not working.

Comment: There is no way to tell why `productEdit` is not defined from the code you've provided. Most likely you got the URL to the script wrong, but that's just wild speculation and I can think of at least three other possible reasons. You need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

As per previous comments regarding duplicate ID attributes - the ID can be modified to become a dataset attribute which do not need to be unique and still allow css rules/selectors to work and allow easy access via Javascript methods if required.

```js
// create a delegated event listener bound to the document in this instance.
// This can handle **ALL** clicks but we only target those of interest.
document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // process click events on the "editItem" buttons only.
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && e.target.dataset.type=='editItem' ){
    
    // send the AJAX request, using the buttons "dataset" attribute for ID
    $.ajax({
        url:"./adminView/editItemForm.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{ record:e.target.dataset.id },
        success:(r)=>{ // yeay! all good
          $('.allContent-section').html( r );
        },
        error:(err)=>{
          console.log('bogus... '+err.statusText)
        }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
[data-type] {
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button data-type="editItem" data-id='666' class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button data-type="editItem" data-id='555' class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button data-type="editItem" data-id='777' class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Because of the sandbox in which Snippets on SO run this will cause errors but you can inspect the network traffic using the console tools and observe that the AJAX request is sent correctly - the `data-id` attributes are assigned within the ajax payload.